# Why Azure DevOps masks some non secret variables in the log output?

Tags: azure-devops

I am logging several guids in the Azure DevOps output, please observe:
[image]

So, the *** (secret) *** is my output, because I know the particular field is a secret. However, the `ClientId` and `TenantId` are masked by Azure DevOps on its own accord and I do not understand how Azure DevOps decided it should be masked.

These are not build variables, just some `Write-Host` statements.

We are using on prem Azure DevOps Server 2019.

**EDIT 1**

Here is the Powershell script that runs:

```
function Initialize-AzureSqlDB(
    [parameter(Mandatory)][ValidateScript({ Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Container })]$DBScriptsSource,    
    [parameter(Mandatory)][string]$SqlServerName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$SqlServerResourceGroup,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$SubscriptionId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$ClientId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$ClientSecret,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$TenantId,
    [string]$DBNamePrefix = "${env:UserName}_"
)
{
    # Some code that does Write-Host for all the script parameters
    ...
```

The script is invoked from a YAML build template. The actual Service principal credentials are found in the ARM_... environment variables. Here is the YAML code:

```
- powershell: Initialize-AzureSqlDB -DBScriptsSource ${{ parameters.dbScriptLocation }} -DBNamePrefix ${{ parameters.dbNamePrefix }} -TenantId $env:ARM_TENANT_ID -SubscriptionId $env:ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID -ClientId $env:ARM_CLIENT_ID -ClientSecret $env:ARM_CLIENT_SECRET -SqlServerName $env:SqlServerName -SqlServerResourceGroup $env:SqlServerResourceGroup 
  displayName: Initializing Database(s).
  condition: eq(variables['RunDBUpgrade'],true)
```

Now neither `ClientId` nor `TenantId` are defined as build variables. Their actual values do come from an exiting Service Connection Endpoint in Azure DevOps, but even there neither are secret.

So, it is unclear to me how Azure DevOps decides to mask them and not `SubscriptionId`, for instance. I, for my part, do not want either of them to be masked.

Can anyone explain how Azure DevOps decides what to mask here?

**EDIT 2**

So, I checked our extension and it contains the following code:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID;]$($se.data.subscriptionId)"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME;]$($se.data.subscriptionName)"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_TENANT_ID;]$($se.auth.parameters.tenantid)"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_ID;isSecret=true]$($se.auth.parameters.serviceprincipalid)"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ARM_CLIENT_SECRET;isSecret=true]$($se.auth.parameters.serviceprincipalkey)"
```

That can explain how `ClientId` gets masked, but not the `TenantId`. Now there is a possibility that the code in the master branch does not exactly match the one installed in server. I will make sure the task is redeployed and then we will know.

Comment: You'll need to provide more context. Where are the client ID and tenant ID variables coming from? A service connection? If that's the case, it's because the author of the extension that provides the service connection decided they should be secret.

Comment: Are the ClientId and TenantId values the same like ClientSecret?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk In Azure, Client ID and Tenant ID are guaranteed to never be the same as they are GUIDs that identify different things.

Comment: @DanielMann Thanks for the info :) I didn't know it.

Comment: @DanielMann - they come from the Service Connection Endpoint in Azure DevOps. We read it using our custom extension. I understand what you are saying. The author of the extension must have declared them as secret, even though they are not and Azure DevOps intercepts all the output and just matches any secret values it knows about. Right?

Comment: Normally Azure Devops would mask those secrets set in variable groups/pipeline variables/task.setvariable+issecret=true. Maybe your extension uses this way `#vso[task.setvariable variable=xxx;issecret=true`?

Comment: I would have to check this. This could explain it.

Comment: Not sure if you've found the case of the issue, you can share it in answer if you've located it. Just a reminder :)

Comment: Please, see EDIT 2.